# Задача про строки в Си

Tags: c, строки

Дано число и какая то строка.
Надо сделать следующее : (проще на примере). Например даны, число `5` и строка `"abc"`.
Надо вывести следующий набор строк :

> "abc-1", "abc-2", "abc-3", "abc-4", "abc-5".

Эти строки должны быть где то сохранены(в массиве строк).

Понятное дело - это не сложная задача, но как это можно сделать проще и оптимальнее именно в Си

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учётом комментария записи в массив попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
    int x = 10; // данное число
    char* s = "Stroka"; // данная строка
    char arr[x][255];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        sprintf(arr[i], "%s-%d", s, i+1); // запись в элемент массива arr[i]
        printf("%s ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

> Stroka-1 Stroka-2 Stroka-3 Stroka-4 Stroka-5 Stroka-6 Stroka-7
>   Stroka-8 Stroka-9 Stroka-10

[Пример](http://ideone.com/PLcEBd).

Comment: не всегда же будет `abc`) и зачем делать i+1 если можно изначально циклу поставить `i=1`

Comment: @tCode спасибо, невнимательно прочитал)

Comment: А `int argc, char *argv[]` на что? А, и при соизмеримо больших `x` всё к чёрту пойдёт. Попробуйте `malloc` что ли.

Answer (score 3):

Если надо просто вывести, то в цикле от 1 до этого числа написать

```
printf("abc-%d", num);
```

где num - счетчик цикла.

Ну или если строка тоже переменная, то

```
printf("%s-%d", str, num);
```

Comment: Нет, надо это сохранить в переменную. То есть у нас есть массив строк, и полученные строки надо в массив сохранить

Comment: @marka_17. Так может это и надо описывать в вопросе???

Comment: @marka_17, тогда можно просто использовать функцию [sprintf](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/sprintf), вместо printf

Comment: @iksuy, да, точно.. Я как то не догадался